# Query database directly or fetch from API in GraphQL resolvers?

Tags: api, architecture, graphql, microservices

I have a microservice application with a few services. I'm planning to implement GraphQL for the application.

An approach I have in mind is to implement a layer of APIs in each of the services first. Then, the GraphQL resolvers would make requests to the services' API endpoints and return them. This method seems neat to me because I will only have one GraphQL endpoint for my frontend to work.

At the same time, however, I'm not sure if this is a good idea at all. Instead of querying against the database directly in my resolvers, I'm actually *making extra HTTP requests* in my resolvers and creating overheads through network transfers. I'm guessing this would impact the overall performance with the extra layer of API calls.

One of the benefits of GraphQL is to prevent over fetching. With that extra layer of API calls in the resolvers, I'm effectively already fetching *all* the fields in the response of the API. Does this sound like another problem with the approach I have described?

When implementing GraphQL in a microservice application, should I have a layer of API for all the services and then have GraphQL resolvers fetching from them, or should I aim to query against the services' database directly in the GraphQL resolvers?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a pretty normal way of doing things. Over-fetching (e.g all the fields on an entity) at the GraphQL <-> Platform boundary is arguably beneficial because you can relatively easily add entity-level caching that's close enough to the source of truth that you can also handle cache invalidation.

Whilst those additional requests do add overhead, you can take advantage of various techniques to reduce it (keep-alive, connection pooling, http2 multiplexing, etc). Ultimately, what you have is a pattern that'll be forced on you anyway once you hit a certain scale.